# How can I take a class out of a namespace automatically with Eclipse CDT?

Tags: c++, eclipse, namespaces, ide, eclipse-cdt

I have a class A that is inside a namespace N in C++, so I can refer to it in the code with N::A.

I need, in Eclipse CDT, to take that class out of the namespace `N`.
Of course, I also need to edit all the occurrencies that refer to such class with the `N::A` notation in the codebase, so that the part referring to the namespace `N` is removed.

I was wondering if, in Eclipse, there is a way to do that automatically, so that I don't have to do it manually everywhere in the code.

Comment: I don't know (but doubt) if that's an automatable refactoring task with Eclipse CDT. The usual way (and that's obe of the valid use cases IMO), is to define a macro for the namespace prefix, and have it conditionally replaced in the preprocessing stage. Must be done consistently, and requires complete recompilation of all affected code of course.

Comment: I would try to replace all occurences of "N::A" to just "A" via text editor's replace all functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One plausible method is by using `using N::A` to load the class `A` to the global namespace. And then you can use the Eclipse CDT's [find and replace](https://rtist.hcldoc.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_find_replace.htm) feature to edit out all the `N::A` occurrences to `A`.

You can either place `using N::A` only in the files where you want the class to be in the global namespace or else you can define it at the end of the class's header file so that it will automatically be defined in every file which includes the class. Using it this way means that only the `A` class gets dumped to the global namespace whereas using `using namespace N;` dumps every single content of that namespace to the global namespace.